# android NDK errors: UnsatisfiedLinkError: hello

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk

I am new to the android NDK, I just tried to build a hello world app using the Android NDK on the Eclipse on a Mac, but I ran into a perplexing issue. The Java and C++ code image is as shown in the following images:

[image: MainActivity.java]

[image: HelloWorld.cpp]

Log cat information image:

[image: Log cat information]

and Android.mk code image:
[image: Android.mk]

could you help me to solve this problem: android NDK errors: UnsatisfiedLinkError: hello, thanks!

Comment: shouldnt your jni folder name be jniLibs or have you included the src path of jni specifically?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answers, I am new one to android NDK, at the beginning, there is errors: Unresolved inclusion: <jni.h>.  In order to solve this error, I browse the include path. Project->New->Folder->Advanced->Link to alternate location(Linked Folder)Browse the path（for example)：C:\Android\android-ndk-r8b\platforms\android-8\arch-arm\usr\include.

Comment: If you need more information, please tell me! I really want to solve this error which trouble me for a day.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it will fix your error but try to add the word **JNICALL** :

`JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_helloworld_MainActivity_hello(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)`

JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are macros used to ensure that the corresponding functions are exported well. In many examples use them when you have a c++ file.

Comment: Without some bit of explanation *why* this might fix the problem, this doesn't help at all.

Comment: Sorry... JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are macros used to ensure that the corresponding functions are exported well. In many examples use them  when you have a c++ file.